rsync options to optimize solid state medium longevity
I usually do my backups via rsync, with
sudo rsync -av --delete --delete-excluded  /home/me/ /media/target

The media target is a usb thumdrive
as far as I understand, thumbdrives suffer more aging from writes than from read (therefore, rsync is making them last longer and be more reliable, because is reads the date of creation and only updates in the relevant case)
my questions

Is my above understanding correct?
Are there rsync options to further optimize the reliability of the thumdrive?

edit:
I don't know the thumbdrive's technology. Is there a general answer, or perhaps a case by case answer?

You mention a USB thumb-drive, which in most cases is a flash storage device, but also solid state which is a SSD type of device. Is your question about an SSD, or what type of USB storage, as they are many types which have different risks/reliability factors involved in them (and obviously different costs).  Are you sure you're not mixing the various types up as if it's a single type.

You need to add the --checksum option to rsync to do checksum comparisons. And in this case all same sized files (i.e., most of your files) will  be read both on the source and the destination. Do you really want to do this? If you use this option, rsync will run veeery slooowly!

@FedKad, does the standard rsync compare only the alteration date marked in the filesystem?

Yes. Please, read the man page: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/rsync.1.html

FYI:  I'm throwing out 6+ thumb-drives per year because they're no longer, as they media whilst extremely handy/useful, is NOT a reliable media for constant writing...  Why I've added a question like Validating an ISO write after write or answers about Media Checks on using live media etc..  I don't backup to thumb-drives; just write ISOs for QA testing of Ubuntu & flavors regularly. Solid State is better

Why not use a proper USB SSD stick instead of junk???
